# colorpicker inside jquery repeater not work when add new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, repeater

I'm using a third party plugin for the color picker compatible with bootstrap, this picker field added in a repeater so I can add rows and remove as I can
I initiate the plugin like the following

```
$('.color-picker').minicolors();
$(".mt-repeater").repeater();
```

but the color picker field not work for the added rows, it only works for the first row.
check the demo on codepen try to click on add row button then on the color picker https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZexeYj 
how can I deal with this issue? when I try to call the minicolors again after adding new row something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the color picker field not work for the added rows, it only works for the first row.

That happens because the color picker is partially initialized on next rows....

According to [jquery.repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) documentation you must handle the **show** option callback:

```
$(".mt-repeater").repeater({
    show: function () {
        $(this).find('.color-picker').minicolors('destroy').minicolors();
        $(this).show();  //  or $(this).slideDown();
    }
});
```

In this method you can destroy the current minicolors and initialize a new one.

Working snippet:

```js
$('.color-picker').minicolors();


$(".mt-repeater").repeater({
    show: function () {
        $(this).find('.color-picker').minicolors('destroy').minicolors();
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.4/jquery.minicolors.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.4/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group mt-repeater">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div data-repeater-list="group-c">
            <div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">
                <div class="row mt-repeater-row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control color-picker" value="#db913d">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control icons-picker">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete">X
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-info mt-repeater-add">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Add row</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another approach is setting initEmpty option to true:

> start with an empty list of repeaters. Set your first (and only)
>   "data-repeater-item" with style="display:none;" and pass the
>   following configuration flag

The snippet:

```js
$(".mt-repeater").repeater({
    initEmpty: true,
    show: function () {
        $(this).find('.color-picker').minicolors();
        $(this).slideDown();
    }
});

// create the first group
$('[data-repeater-create]').trigger('click');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.4/jquery.minicolors.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.4/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mt-repeater">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div data-repeater-list="group-c">
            <div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item" style="display:none;">
                <div class="row mt-repeater-row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control color-picker" value="#db913d">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control icons-picker">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete">X
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-info mt-repeater-add">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Add row</a>
    </div>
</div>
```